# SAPUI5: What are strengths and weaknesses of the sap.m.Shell and sap.m.App as container for an application wrapper?

Tags: javascript, shell, wrapper, sapui5

What are strengths and weaknesses of the
sap.m.Shell
and
sap.m.App
as container for an SAPUI5 application wrapper?
I currently use non of them, but I see the advantages.
SAP best practise is to use one of them or nest them as shell > app. What are strengths and weaknesses of the approaches?

Comment: Also see this [Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31473848/1969374)

Answer (score 2):

**`sap.m.Shell`**: The Shell control can be used as root element of applications, it can contain an App or `SplitApp` control. The Shell provides some overarching functionality for the overall application and takes care of visual adaptation, like a frame around the App, on desktop browser platforms. Gives interface to logout,set homebackgroud and other stuff. App is an aggregation for shell. Basically allows to have user level settings and so on

**`sap.m.App`** : App is the root element of a UI5 mobile application. It inherits from `NavContainer` and thus provides its navigation capabilities. It also adds certain header tags to the HTML page which are considered useful for mobile apps.
This acts like an container for your views with navigation features.

**Best Practice:** To nest them as app inside a shell. So that you have clear separation between apps and under one shell. Shell provides more features than sap.m.App though you can achieve them in crude way. According to me nesting them is best solution.