# When to use Shell, App, Container, Page, View, and SplitApp

Tags: sapui5

Recently I have created two UI5 apps using shell -> views and appContainer -> views. Both results in same output. I'm confused when to use Shell, App, Container, Page, View, and SplitApp in UI5.

I would like to know the differences between them. 
Also please describe the best practices of using the above containers from your experiences.

Graphical explanation would help a lot in understanding.

Answer (score 41):

You're right, there are a lot of container controls and this can be confusing. So let me give a brief overview:

### sap.m.Shell

The shell, no surprise here, is a parent container you can use for views. However, in contrast to other containers, it allows you to limit the app width for large devices. If you want to achieve this for your application, this is your control.

[image: sap.m.Shell]

### sap.m.App | sap.m.SplitApp

Both, the `sap.m.App` and the `sap.m.SplitApp` are probably the most used parent controls. In fact, one of them should always be part of your mobile application as they do some HTML modifications to improve the experience on mobile devices (see [sap/ui/util/Mobile.init](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/module%3Asap%2Fui%2Futil%2FMobile/methods/sap%2Fui%2Futil%2FMobile.init) for details). Of course, they can be a child of any Shell. Furthermore, they are important since they extend a `sap.m.NavContainer` and therefore offer navigation capabilities. For example, the `sap.m.App` has a `pages` aggregation. By calling `to`, you can simply navigate from one page to another (once you are using routing, this is done by the router). The `sap.m.SplitApp` contains two NavContainers. One for the Master Area and another for the Detail Area. In addition, it offers you to manage one background across your application.

### sap.m.SplitContainer

Talking about containers one should mention the `sap.m.SplitContainer`. Basically, it offers the same capabilities as the `sap.m.SplitApp` but since you should have only one App (`sap.m.App` or `sap.m.SplitApp`) in your application, you can use this control if you want to start a Master/Detail view once you navigate deeper in your application.

### sap.ui.core.mvc.View

The view (and all of its sub types like `JSView`, `XMLView`, `HTMLView`) reflect one simple page or area of a page. In contrast to all other containers, a view may have a controller associated and enables you to implement the View/Controller part of MVC.

### sap.ui.core.Fragment

Fragments are light-weight variants of a view. They are used like views and they behave similar, but have no controller associated by default. However, you can use simple objects with functions as a controller replacement if necessary. Fragments can be used if you have a particular part of the User Interface you want to externalize to a different file (and maybe reuse it multiple times).

### Examples

Regarding an architecture of your application, it depends on what you want to display (limited app width, Master/Detail, ...). Almost every combination is possible but I think it is still best practices to have only one App object per application. If you don´t need a feature of one of the Shells you can simply omit it and make your app object the top level container. Some examples for an architecture could look like this:

**SplitApp or SplitContainer in a sap.m.Shell**

```
sap.m.Shell
    sap.m.SplitApp
        sap.ui.core.view.XMLView (Master)
            sap.m.Page

        sap.ui.core.view.XMLView (Detail)
            sap.m.Page
```

[image: ui5 master detail pages within splitapp within shell]

---

**SplitApp or SplitContainer without Shell**

```
sap.m.SplitApp
    sap.ui.core.view.XMLView (Master)
        sap.m.Page

    sap.ui.core.view.XMLView (Detail)
        sap.m.Page
```

[image: ui5 master detail pages within splitapp without shell]

---

**sap.m.App in a sap.m.Shell**

```
sap.m.Shell
    sap.m.App
        sap.ui.core.view.JSView
            sap.m.Page
```

[image: ui5 page within view within app within shell]

---

**sap.m.App without any Shell**

```
sap.m.App
    sap.ui.core.view.XMLView
        sap.m.Page
```

[image: ui5 page within view within app without shell]

Comment: Valuable Information, helps a lot for beginners. SAP SDK should've this content.

Comment: You might add `<VBox>` as an undecorated element below a `<Page>`

Comment: Thank you. Nice overview with the graphics.